# mysql group by day with count multi types of records

Tags: mysql

i have a table with `id | type | publishedon`
type may be 1,2,3 or 4 (int) value
i want to select posts for every day
now i'm using

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME( `publishedon` , "%Y-%m-%d" ) AS `day` , count( id ) AS listings,
TYPE FROM posts
WHERE (
FROM_UNIXTIME( publishedon ) >= SUBDATE( NOW( ) , 30 )
)
GROUP BY `day`
```

the result

```
day     listings
2013-09-02  17
2013-09-05  105
```

i want make listings filed more detailed like

```
day     type_1   type_2   type_3   type_4
2013-09-02  10      4       6        3
2013-09-05  6      4       1        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to put all your `type` values:

```
SELECT 
  FROM_UNIXTIME( `publishedon` , "%Y-%m-%d" ) AS `day`, 
  count(id) AS listings,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `posts` WHERE `type`=1 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(`publishedon`, "%Y-%m-%d")=`day`) AS `type_1`,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `posts` WHERE `type`=2 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(`publishedon`, "%Y-%m-%d")=`day`) AS `type_2`,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `posts` WHERE `type`=3 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(`publishedon`, "%Y-%m-%d")=`day`) AS `type_3`,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `posts` WHERE `type`=4 AND FROM_UNIXTIME(`publishedon`, "%Y-%m-%d")=`day`) AS `type_4`
FROM 
  `posts`
WHERE
  FROM_UNIXTIME(`publishedon`) >= SUBDATE(NOW(), 30)
GROUP BY 
  `day`
```

but in fact, that will work slow since there are functions in conditions. If it is only a formatting matter, it's better to act like:

```
SELECT 
  FROM_UNIXTIME(`publishedon`, "%Y-%m-%d" ) AS `day`, 
  `type`,
  count( id ) AS listings,
FROM 
  `posts`
WHERE
-- this should be better evaluated in application 
-- since will not produce index using too:
  FROM_UNIXTIME(`publishedon`) >= SUBDATE(NOW(), 30)
GROUP BY 
  `day`,
  `type`
```

and then create desired formatting inside application.

Comment: what do you mean? do you have alternative instead of "FROM_UNIXTIME(`publishedon`) >= SUBDATE(NOW(), 30)"

Comment: yes, I have. Inside an application, evaluate subtraction of current timestamp and 30 days (i.e. 30*24*3600 seconds). In php that will be `time() - 30*24*3600` - let this value be $x. Then your condition will be: `WHERE publishedon>$x` - this is constant, no functions in it, so index will be used (if present)

Comment: that mean using functions in where is bad

Comment: It's not bad in common case. My point is - that you can avoid using them - you should since MySQL will never use indexes if there are functions in the corresponding condition expressions.